# ApiMember attribute not showing up in ServiceStack generated metadata

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack, and I'd like to help the "auto documentation" of the generated metadata out.

I recently found the `ApiAttribute` and the `ApiMemberAttribute` ([mentioned here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172817/documenting-servicestack-web-services/7199335#7199335)). However, I *cannot* get the `http://me/api/metadata?op=ReadFormType` page to emit any information for the decorated member.

He is a stripped down version of my DTO (it's just a stub so far) that uses a test property:

```
[Api("Read FormType")]
[Route("/formTypes/{FormType}", "GET")]
public class ReadFormType
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "X", Description = "X Description",
        ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string X { get; set; }
}
```

The `ApiAttribute` text *does* correctly appear at the top of the metadata response and the member *is* listed correctly in the Request DTO section below.

What do I need to do in order to make the extra information in `ApiMemberAttribute` appear? (Or am I misunderstanding how this attribute works?)

The version of ServiceStack is 3.9.35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Api` and `ApiMember` attributes are currently used in [ServiceStack's Swagger support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API).

But we'll also include them to ServiceStack's auto-generated metadata pages in the next version of ServiceStack.